# How does Parse's iOS SDK (or other SDK's for that matter) resolve conflicts?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, data-synchronization, merge-conflict-resolution

In distributed systems, conflicts are unavoidable.  You can see a simple explanation of this from [this video from Couchbase](http://youtu.be/mFQTGiCEHrE?t=34m46s).

Parse over-simplifies data-syncing in the documentation, saying that you don't have to worry a thing: `saveEventually` will ensure your changes will eventually be uploaded, and when performing `fetch`, remote changes will update your local data (see https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore-saving/iOS).

However, conflicts will occur. There's no mention of how conflict resolution can be handled. How is it handled?

Comment: Not sure if/how parse overcomes this, but I overcome it by not using saveEventually.  If I think a query might happen when execution continues after a save, I use a form of save that tells me when it's finished. (in iOS, ...WithCompletion:)

Answer (score 0):

Parse does not handle conflicts and you would need to avoid the situation on the app client side or write complex Cloud Code to handle the concurrency scheme or management of data versions and then merge or delete accordingly.  This is difficult and tedious overall.

For Couchbase and Couchbase Mobile, an entire revision tree is kept and you as a app developer can control how to handle the conflicts on the document through the APIs.

I wrote a [blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/migration-from-parse-to-couchbase) that mentions this briefly and how to resolve for conflicts.